# Java Swing JPanel Sizes

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint

I would like to be able to have a JPanel within my JFrame of a fixed size 400x400.

I would also like the to be a 20px wide border all around it.

The main problem is the following code doesnt stick it its size.`   JScrollPane runningAni = new JScrollPane(new views.cRunningAnimation(
                model));

```
    runningAni.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400,400));

    this.setSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    this.add(runningAni,BorderLayout.CENTER);`
```

When doing this the runningAni panel just strethces accross the whole frame.

```
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

    this.setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));
    }
```

I know this because my full frame paints itself green rather than just the JPanel (The above paint code is for my panel not the frame)

How would i create the panel so it always stays the same size and so there is always a 20px colored border around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BorderLayout` ignores the size. You need to set a `LayoutManager` that either allows you to set the size to a fixed size or one that cares for the sizes set. There are different layout managers that allow this (e.g. `GrindBagLayout` <strike>or no layout manager at all</strike>). Some are not that easy to use (e.g. `GridBagLayout`). What to use depends on the rest of the layout.

You could probably use a layout panel that contains your custom panel. The layout panel needs an appropriate layout manager and could be put into the center of the `BorderLayout`. This would mean nearly no modifications to existing layout code.

The whole point of `BorderLayout` is to fill the center with the center component.

Comment: I like this +1 ! How would i be able to set a border around my Jpanel e..g add Border adds it inside?

Comment: @LmC There are different ways to achieve this, of course. Best would be if your custom component would handle `setBorder(Border)` correctly. Just set an `EmptyBorder`. But then you would have to add this border to the component's size calculation. If the containing component's layout manager knows about padding (e.g. `GridBagLayout`, `BorderLayout`) you could use this. NB: I don't recommend GBL, there are much, much better LayoutManagers, but evaluating LayoutManagers is out of scope here.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet You are right, but with the demand for 400x400 the problem already exists on a deeper, earlier level. Asking for a specific size (in pixels!) is the primary problem; what layout manager to use to achieve this (`null`, `AbsoluteLayout`, a parametric like GBL or `FormLayout` with fixed values) doesn't matter much. But I striked that part so it is clear I have my doubt there too.

Comment: @his If you want to achieve that, simply override `getPreferredSize()` and return whatever dimension you need. This will avoid any unwanted call to `setPreferredSize`. Of course, you also need to choose a Layout that respects the preferred size. Thanks for striking that option from your answer. I find it much better now :-) Cheers. Why not recommending GBL?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet The problem in my view is the requirement for "400px x 400px". There is nearly no situation where such an requirement should exist at all, the UI should be fluent and adapt to different sizes. When it does, it doesn't make a big difference which method one chooses to get the pixel sizes. The requirements are bad, the result will be bad. When trying to reach a wrong goal, the fastest way is the best, no matter how bad the reputation is (i.e. null layout). GBL is too complicated and error prone to use, other LMs like JGoodies FormLayout lead to the same result easier and cleaner.

Comment: Still I don't want to actively advocate pro null layout, so thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Don't override the paint() method to set the color of the panel. Use:

```
panel.setBackground(...);
```

When you create the panel.

> How would i be able to set a border around my Jpanel

See [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just set your layout to null, to what ever class your adding your JPanel.
Then use the setBounds() method to set your location and size!

For example:

```
public class Main extends JFrame{

      YourPanelClass panel = new YourPanelClass();

      public Main(){

           // I didn't want to put all the, everyday JFrame methods...

           setLayout(null);

           /*
               First two coordinates indicate the location of JPanel inside JFrame.
               The seconds set of coordinates set the size of your JPanel.
               (The first two coordinates, 0 and 0, tell the JPanel to start at the
                   top left of your JFrame.)
           */
           panel.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);

           add(panel);
      }
}
```

And i would **GREATLY** recommend using the paintComponent() method.

For instance:
(Obviously you put this in your JPanel's class.)

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     super.paintComponent(g); // don't forget this if you are going to use this method.

     //Basically this makes your JPanel's background green(I did it this way because I like doing it this way better.)
     g.setColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));
     g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

**Please don't forget to thumbs up if this helped!**

Answer (score -1):

```
setPreferredSize()
setMinimumSize()
setMaximumSize()
```

should do the trick

Comment: Bad idea, poor advice. Those methods should be forgotten

Comment: This answer isn't even remotely correct. The need to use these methods is rare, although I don't think they need to be forgotten as mentioned above. They still have their uses for occasional adjustments.